# Add child category to multiple parent category in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.5, categories, magento-1.6

I want to assign a specific child category to multiple parent categories .

For e.g, If there are 2 parent categories ,say, Dell Laptop and  Sony Laptop and a child category named as Laptop accessories. I want to include the "Laptop Accessories" category in both "Dell Laptop" and "Sony Laptop" .

By default,this functionality is not in Magento, I need to create 2 child categories named as "Laptop accessories" and then assign it to parent categories.

How can I solve this issue? Does any have worked on it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Category Parent Child relationships in Magento are one to many (one parent category has many children, each child has exactly one parent).  The database schema does not allow what you want to do.

If your issue is creating the multiple "Laptop" categories quickly, consider creating your categories as a CSV and using a tool like Unirgy's RapidFlow to import them, or alternatively writing a setup script.

Comment: hi Jim, but this is not happening!! I mean Magento is such a huge platform and might having some ways to achieve this

Comment: Magento is a huge platform.  But I reviewed the database schema before I answered the question, and it's not technically possible.  If a third party extension were to try and provide this capability, it would need to rewrite/override some very core aspects of the system, and I'm not sure I'd be comfortable with that.

Comment: Additionally your issue may be one of information architecture.  If the laptop accessories in your example relate to both brands of laptops, then it probably belongs as a standalone category at the same level in your category hierarchy as the two laptop categories.  If the products in in the Sony > Laptop Accessories are different to the products in Dell > Laptop accessories, then you really do have two separate categories (they just happen to have the same name).